# Struggling with ES6 features of Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, dictionary, methods, ecmascript-6

I am just exploring ES6. I can see the value in the update, but I am struggling with a class method.

```
class Item{
  constructor(name){
    this.name=name;
  }
}
class Park extends Item{
  constructor(name, numberoftrees, size){
    super(name);
    this.numberoftrees=numberoftrees;
    this.size=size;
  }
  classifyPark(){
    const classification = new Map();
    classification.set(1, "SMALL");
    classification.set(2, "MEDIUM");
    classification.set(3, "LARGE");
    console.log(`${this.name} park is sized: ${classification.get(this.size)} and has
    ${this.numberoftrees} trees.`)
  }
}



var Park1 = new Park();
Park1.name=prompt('ENTER NAME OF PARK');
Park1.numberoftrees=prompt('ENTER # OF TREES');
Park1.size=parseInt(prompt('ENTER SIZE'));


function reportPark(parks){
  console.log("PARK REPORT>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
  parks.forEach(item=>item.classifyPark());
}
reportPark(parks);
```

Why do I need classifyPark as a method of my class? Why shouldn't I just create a separate Map and access it directly? I'm following a udemy course but no one has answered this in the Q&A and I am just completely confused.

classifyPark just creates our map, and then uses the size property as a key in the map to console log the value. Is that it? This seems like a kinda crazy way to do things.

Comment: Yep, the `classification` `Map` seems completely useless, because the `classifyPark` function never uses it. Is that the whole code?

Comment: When you have a suspicion like that, it's a code smell. Trust your instinct and question its necessity.

Comment: I realize now the value of this. Objects (in javascript classes are a type of object) can have properties or methods, so the classifyPark method allows us to essentially attach the map it will create. I'm sure there is another way to attach the map as a property, but this is a pretty clever solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial example, but it's illustrating that`classifyPark` accesses variables from the `Item` class by using `this`.

```
console.log(`${this.name} park is sized: ${classification.get(this.size)} and has ${this.numberoftrees} trees.`)
```

In the "real world", class methods are typically more complex and can use class variables and other class methods to do more complex things.

Another trivial example, but maybe something a little more helpful

```
class Circle {
  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }

  area() {
    return 3.14*this.radius*this.radius;
  }

  circumference() {
    return 3.14*this.radius;
  }

}

const circle = new Circle();
console.log(circle.area());
console.log(circle.radius());
```

The idea of putting `area` and `circumference` on `Circle` rather than having helper functions is around encapsulating the logic. The circle knows how to compute its own radius and circumference.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you! Great example!